# Adding extra fields to an existing namedtuple object and unpickling

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, namedtuple

I have some data in the pickled format with instances of below objects:

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x',])
```

Now I want to extend the Point object to add another variable 'y' but also keep this compatible with the data I already have pickled.

Below is what I tried, but seems to fail. I also tried playing around with the code to make a Point class by setting the y parameter as optional when making the Point object, but that did not work as well. Any ideas on how to proceed?

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x'])
i = Point(1)
import cPickle
pick=cPickle.dumps(i)
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
cPickle.loads(pick)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 22, in __repr__
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: You would have to unpickle _before_ redefining `Point`.

Comment: If you're saying you want to have `Point`s that can either have an `x` attribute _or_ an `x` and `y` attribute, I don't think you can do that with a `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are immutable.
Unpickle first, than make a new point with a different namedtuple class and use the attribute `x` from the old point.
Using the same name for the class `Point` should have the effect you are after:

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x'])
i = Point(1)
pick=cPickle.dumps(i)


def unpickle_point(dumped_obj):
    Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x'])
    point = cPickle.loads(pick)
    Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
    return Point(point.x, 2)

new_point = unpickle_point(pick)
```

Now:

```
>>> new_point
Point(x=1, y=2)
```

Comment: This is essentially creating a new instance and using that which I cannot really do. Is there a way to define a custom class which is compatible with the old Point object?

Comment: Well, unpickling always creates a new instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible"?  A tuple has either one or two elements. It cannot have both, because it is immutable.

Comment: Yes. Let me rephrase it. When I will unpickle the object I can only have one Point definition which has to be the new/ custom object which supports y variable. So I need to somehow define a class which is compatible with the already pickled objects. Makes sense?

Comment: by compatible i mean that I should be able to unpickle the old Point object with the new definition. And Yes i agree that a tuple has either one or two elements, but can i define a custom named tuple whose one parameter is optional.

Comment: For example If i make the y parameter optional in the code I get by executing the below line:
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'], verbose=true)
I can then do something like, p = Point(1), but one thing to note is that p.y will be set to the default parameter. So when I unpickle the old object i would want the y variable to be set to the default parameter

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Minor: you want to `unpickle_point(pick)`, not `unpickle_point(i)`, here.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you demand that:

1. the unpickler shall take strings produced when the name `Point` meant something with *one* argument; but
2. at that time, `Point` shall mean something produced with *two* arguments

... then you have kind of painted yourself into a corner, by demanding the impossible.  By default, both the pickling and unpickling are done by encoding (pickle) and decoding (unpickle) *all* the values that go with the object.  The object named `Point` has one value.  No, it has two values!  Well, pick one or the other: it cannot have both.

You can, as in [Mike Müller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999504/1256452), make the name `Point` refer to the one-valued `Point` for the duration of the unpickling, then make the name `Point` refer to the two-valued `Point` afterward.  That will work, at the expense of a lot of type-defining and name manipulation.  You can lower the overall cost (pretty significantly) by not re-creating the types themselves.  Here's how:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import sys

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x'])
i = Point(1)
import cPickle
pick = cPickle.dumps(i)

old_style_point = Point
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

def unpickle_point(dumped_obj):
    """Make main.Point refer to the old style point for the
    duration of the pickle.loads() operation, then back to
    the new style Point afterward."""
    mod = sys.modules[__name__]  # eg, sys.modules['__main__']
    save = mod.__dict__['Point']
    try:
        mod.__dict__['Point'] = old_style_point
        old_point = cPickle.loads(dumped_obj)
    finally:
        mod.__dict__['Point'] = save
    return Point(old_point.x, 2)

t = unpickle_point(pick)
print(t)
```

This code works in Python 3 as well (provided you switch from `cPickle` to `pickle`).  The `try`/`finally` sequence here means that if you run this on bad data, the type name `Point` will continue to refer to the *new* `Point` object, not the old one in `old_style_point`.  As always, though, pickled strings are not secure and if you cannot trust them, you should not be doing this at all, so this particular bit of `try`/`finally` can just be removed if the data are that trustworthy.  (But the fact that you're doing this at all suggests that the data *aren't* that trustworthy.)